# Dynamic Memeory Allocation allocates lines in caches or not?

Tags: linux, caching, malloc, allocation

Using dynamic memory allocation at runtime in Linux allocates some memory in RAM. However, I want to know whether the **cache** lines are also allocated in the **cache** for that memory at the same time or not.

E.g, After I allocated some memory using `malloc()` and I store 4 bytes of data (cache line may be 4 or 16 Bytes) will the write miss occur on cache or not?

Comment: This is not done explicitly.  As a matter of fact, after the `malloc()`, you may not even have **real** memory.  When you access the memory a *page fault* may occur and a *data abort* handler will allocate the memory for you.  Generally a *user space* program can not **lock** cpu cache lines.  As your code has just ran, depending on circumstances, it may be in the **cache**.  However, every thing depends on system load.  You might want to visit [man mlock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html)